# Gradient filter

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I would like to do a non-color gradient, but am not sure how.

For example applying a blur filter in gradient. I.e., imagine the left side of the gradient fill area would be "normal", and as you go right, it would be more and more blury.

I'm exemplifying with "blur", but I need to achieve this with other kinds of filter too. Is there any systematic way of doing it easily?

I am using Inkscape.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to link intensity of filter application to a mask?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Well put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not available right now in straightforward manner: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/172099, but…

I'd try to "simulate" it by duplicating objects you want to add effect to, applying effect and adding a transparency mask to them (here's the example of transparency mask: http://howto.nicubunu.ro/inkscape_gimp_reflections/). That way you'll have "untouched" objects below and objects with applied effect and transparency mask above. It'll give the impression of effect "fading-away".

Comment: Hmm, the result is not quite what I was expecting. I started experimenting with a blur filter. The filter makes the object not only blured around the edges but a bit transparent too. So, having the original object below spoils the effect... What I've tried next was to create two symmetric gradient masks, apply one to the original object, apply the other to the blured object, and overlap the two objects. This *almost* works well... as it requires a lot of tweaking to the get the gradients just right.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the way for now :(. But… every draw back is also an opportunity for improvements. Maybe some great, new interface or workflow will emerge out of this? I encourage you to think how one could solve this problem and let devs know about it (e.g. on mailing list).